# Restart ea-tomcat85 from crontab

Tags: linux, cron, tomcat, crontab

I have written a script to restart tomcat service

```
# timestamp
ts=`date +%m-%d-%Y_%H:%M:%S`
echo "$ts: Restarting ea-tomcat85..." &>> /home/account_name/restartservice.log
ubic restart ea-tomcat85 &>> /home/account_name/restartservice.log
```

I want to run this script daily just before midnight using crontab, but the cron job is throwing an error

```
/home/acount_name/restartservice.sh: line 4: ubic: command not found
```

Can someone help me with this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by updating the contab entry

```
53 23 * * * PATH=$(dirname $(readlink /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/perl)):$PATH ubic restart ea-tomcat85 &>> /home/account_name/ea-tomcat85/myscript/restart-tomcat-service.log
```

I hope this helps someone.